# Pagination having issues with page id

Tags: php, javascript, pagination

If i have 10 data in page=1 in pagination,another page having i.e page=2 having another 10 data.and after that page=3 doesn't contain any data.if i select previous button then that page goes in page-1,page=-2.....and if i press next button,it will also going on like page=2,page=3 and so on.So how to disable prev and next button if the record is no longer available ?

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); 
    $start = 0;
    $per_page = 5;
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = 1;
    } else{
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    if($page<=1)
        $start = 0;
    else
        $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
        $sql="select id,question,correctAnswer,category from math order by id";
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
        $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
        $sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))                  
        { ?>
         .......            
         ........
      <?php
      $prev = $page - 1;
      $next = $page + 1;
      echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
      echo " <a href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";
      ?>
```

Comment: Tip: You should validate and escape all user input to avoid injection. Also check the manual on those `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); 
    $start = 0;
    $per_page = 5;
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = 1;
    } else{
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    if($page<=1)
        $start = 0;
    else
        $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
        $sql="select id,question,correctAnswer,category from math order by id";
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
        $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
        $sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))                  
        { ?>
         .......            
         ........
      <?php

      if($page > 1){
         $prev = $page - 1;
         $prev = " <a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
      } else {
         $prev = "";
      }
      if($page < $num_pages){
         $next = $page + 1;
         $next = " <a href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";
      }
      echo $prev;
      echo $next;
      ?>
```

Comment: And also, change $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page; to $num_pages = floor($num_rows / $per_page)

This will round off any uneven numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); 
    $start = 0;
    $per_page = 5;
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = 1;
    } else{
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    if($page<=1)
        $start = 0;
    else
        /*add these lines*/
        $cnt=mysql_query("select count(*) as ct from math") or die(mysql_error());
        $data=mysql_fetch_array($cnt);
        $total = $data['ct'];
        $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
        $sql="select id,question,correctAnswer,category from math order by id";
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
        $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
        $sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))                  
        { ?>
         .......            
         ........
      <?php
      $prev = $page - 1;
      $next = $page + 1;
      /*also add these condition*/
      if($page > 1)
           echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
      /*also add these condition*/
      if($total > ($page*$per_page))
           echo " <a href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";
      ?>
```

> Note: Always use the PDO or mysqli_* as mysql_* is deprecated in
>   latest PHP version. This will be good practice for future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
include("config.php"); 
$per_page = 5;
$page = (is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0);
$sql = "SELECT `id`,`question`,`correctAnswer`,`category` FROM `math` ORDER BY `id`";
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
$num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);
$sql .= " LIMIT ".$per_page*$page.", {$per_page}";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
.......           
........
<?php
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a> ";
echo " <a href='?page=$next'>next</a> ";
?>
```

Comment: Thank You Nils for rpl..But It gives me error like:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-5, 5' at line 1

Comment: Are you sure you're using this exact code? Cause $per_page as it is 5, and $page, as by default would be 0 — 5*0=0, which can't create -5.

Though, try replacing $page = (is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0); to 
$page = (is_numeric($_GET['page']) && > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 0);